# getting conflicting files error from libgpg-error while updating with pacman

Tags: linux, arch-linux, pacman

on arch linux, Kernel: 6.2.13-arch1-1
trying to update with `pacman -Syu` but am getting these error messages

```
error: failed to commit transaction (conflicting files)
libgpg-error: /usr/bin/gpg-error exists in filesystem
libgpg-error: /usr/bin/gpgrt-config exists in filesystem
libgpg-error: /usr/bin/yat2m exists in filesystem
libgpg-error: /usr/include/gpg-error.h exists in filesystem
libgpg-error: /usr/include/gpgrt.h exists in filesystem
libgpg-error: /usr/lib/libgpg-error.so exists in filesystem
libgpg-error: /usr/lib/libgpg-error.so.0 exists in filesystem
libgpg-error: /usr/lib/libgpg-error.so.0.34.0 exists in filesystem
libgpg-error: /usr/lib/pkgconfig/gpg-error.pc exists in filesystem
libgpg-error: /usr/share/aclocal/gpg-error.m4 exists in filesystem
libgpg-error: /usr/share/aclocal/gpgrt.m4 exists in filesystem
libgpg-error: /usr/share/common-lisp/source/gpg-error/gpg-error-codes.lisp exists in filesystem
libgpg-error: /usr/share/common-lisp/source/gpg-error/gpg-error-package.lisp exists in filesystem
libgpg-error: /usr/share/common-lisp/source/gpg-error/gpg-error.asd exists in filesystem
libgpg-error: /usr/share/common-lisp/source/gpg-error/gpg-error.lisp exists in filesystem
libgpg-error: /usr/share/info/gpgrt.info.gz exists in filesystem
libgpg-error: /usr/share/libgpg-error/errorref.txt exists in filesystem
libgpg-error: /usr/share/locale/cs/LC_MESSAGES/libgpg-error.mo exists in filesystem
libgpg-error: /usr/share/locale/da/LC_MESSAGES/libgpg-error.mo exists in filesystem
libgpg-error: /usr/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/libgpg-error.mo exists in filesystem
libgpg-error: /usr/share/locale/eo/LC_MESSAGES/libgpg-error.mo exists in filesystem
libgpg-error: /usr/share/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES/libgpg-error.mo exists in filesystem
libgpg-error: /usr/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/libgpg-error.mo exists in filesystem
libgpg-error: /usr/share/locale/hu/LC_MESSAGES/libgpg-error.mo exists in filesystem
libgpg-error: /usr/share/locale/it/LC_MESSAGES/libgpg-error.mo exists in filesystem
libgpg-error: /usr/share/locale/ja/LC_MESSAGES/libgpg-error.mo exists in filesystem
libgpg-error: /usr/share/locale/nl/LC_MESSAGES/libgpg-error.mo exists in filesystem
libgpg-error: /usr/share/locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES/libgpg-error.mo exists in filesystem
libgpg-error: /usr/share/locale/pt/LC_MESSAGES/libgpg-error.mo exists in filesystem
libgpg-error: /usr/share/locale/ro/LC_MESSAGES/libgpg-error.mo exists in filesystem
libgpg-error: /usr/share/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/libgpg-error.mo exists in filesystem
libgpg-error: /usr/share/locale/sr/LC_MESSAGES/libgpg-error.mo exists in filesystem
libgpg-error: /usr/share/locale/sv/LC_MESSAGES/libgpg-error.mo exists in filesystem
libgpg-error: /usr/share/locale/tr/LC_MESSAGES/libgpg-error.mo exists in filesystem
libgpg-error: /usr/share/locale/uk/LC_MESSAGES/libgpg-error.mo exists in filesystem
libgpg-error: /usr/share/locale/vi/LC_MESSAGES/libgpg-error.mo exists in filesystem
libgpg-error: /usr/share/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/libgpg-error.mo exists in filesystem
libgpg-error: /usr/share/locale/zh_TW/LC_MESSAGES/libgpg-error.mo exists in filesystem
libgpg-error: /usr/share/man/man1/gpgrt-config.1.gz exists in filesystem
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

any ideas? i tried doing `pacman -S --overwrite glob libgpg-error`
but the same error happens

i tried doing `$ pacman -Qo /usr/bin/gpg-error`
but got `error: No package owns /usr/bin/gpg-error`

doing the following also gives the previous longer error with the list of the existing files

```
$ pacman -Syu --overwrite gpg-error
$ pacman -Syu --overwrite glob *
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the wildcard to stop the shell from expanding it.

Do either of:

```
sudo pacman -S --overwrite \* <package_name>
sudo pacman -S --overwrite "*" <package_name>
```

Source :
[pacman "exists on filesystem" error](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/240252/pacman-exists-on-filesystem-error).